# log4j2 not logging to a file

Tags: log4j2, rollingfileappender

Java 1.8, WebSphere Liberty 19.0.0.3 running in localhost, log4j v.2.17.1, Maven v.3.5.2

I have read some posts of similar issues, but I have not seen a solution that works for my case.

I cannot get anything to write to the log files.  Presently, I am focusing on the root logger, as that writes to both the console and to file.

Pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the configuration for the root logger:

```
<Root>
    <!-- change level to EROR -->
    <Level value="TRACE"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="APS-FILE"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
</Root>
```

The root logger is correctly calling the STDOUT appender and writing to the console.  Note the pair of asterisks.  Those match the output I am seeing in the console.

```
<Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>"** %d{DATE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n **"</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
</Console>
```

console output:

```
"** 07 Jan 2022 09:50:42,331  INFO WSWebSsoFilter:44 - Exiting WSWebSsoFilter.doFilter **"
"** 07 Jan 2022 09:50:42,331  INFO WSWebSsoFilter:44 - Exiting WSWebSsoFilter.doFilter **"
```

This is the appender configuration for root logger to write to file.

```
<RollingFile name="APS-FILE" fileName="/logs/aps/${company-code}/aps-A.log"
    filePattern="logs/aps/${company-code}/aps-1.log">
    <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>"%d{DATE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="0"/>
        <!--SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/-->
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB"/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
</RollingFile>
```

The OnStartupTriggeringPolicy is firing, as you can see from this file:

```
LastWriteTime         Length Name
------------------    ------ --------- 
1/7/2022   9:49 AM         0 aps-A.log
```

Any ideas about how to fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: Your `filePattern` does not have a leading `/`, hence the rotated file is created in another folder. (It also does not have an integer pattern `%i`: there will be only one rotated file `aps-1.log`)

Answer (score -2):

Try to change the STDOUT target to your rolling file appender

```
<Console name="STDOUT" target="**APS-FILE**">
    <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>"** %d{DATE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n **"</Pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
</Console>
```